# Warming cold hands and feet

Tags: backcountry, weather, resources

I'm seeing great tips on here about swinging arms and legs to warm cold feet and hands in frigid conditions, but it dates back a bit. I'm looking to include 'field-tested' info on this in a magazine article I'm working on - is anyone willing to provide details? I'd be most grateful!